# Vitepress use external library react library

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vite, vitepress

Facing a pretty wierd bug. I want to use the external react library like this https://shoelace.style/frameworks/react in the vitepress. While running the app in the dev with `npm run docs:dev` is works fine but doesn't when the build is served.

The error thrown is
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')`

This is the code playground for the same: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dnqmyv?file=docs%2FFooBar.jsx,docs%2Findex.md,docs%2F.vitepress%2Fconfig.ts

My thoughts here is that this is due to the components getting rendered on the server maybe. But I have tried to cover this up by following methods:

- Rending (& importing) after the mount

```
    onMounted(async () => {
        const {default: FooBar} = await import("./FooBar.jsx")
        const root = createRoot(el.value)
        root.render(createElement(FooBar, {}, null))
    })
```

- Using `ClientOnly` provided by vitepress for rendering on the Client

```
    <ClientOnly><div ref="el" /></ClientOnly>
```

Additional Context:

- I am using vitepress for the ssg for the docs. I really liked the UI.
- I am using `@vitejs/plugin-react` for using react in vitepress.

Comment: What is the question? It's unclear if the attempt to run code on client side only was successful

Comment: What I meant is that while the application functions flawlessly during development, it encounters issues when serving the built version. The specific nature of the problem remains unclear which I am not sure about (and the reason I posted this question). Additionally, VitePress lacks a straightforward way to disable server-side rendering (SSR), hindering efforts to test the client-only approach as a potential solution.

Comment: Both approaches are common for SSR/SSG. The docs seem to cover this exhaustively https://vitepress.dev/guide/ssr-compat .

Comment: Yeah, have checked that out but can't find the solution over there!